# How to find out which columns are similar in two sql tables based on their values?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have two tables in MySQL with 100+ columns. I need to figure out the columns in both tables which have some of the same values. I need a way to find out which columns are matching in terms of type and values in them so that I can use them in joins and extract results from them. I can convert the tables in excel sheet and apply VB Script as well. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a terrible design for performing this kind of query

Comment: Yup, that's true but that's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magical SQL query you can run to determine the logic behind how your database was designed. You can check the table schema to see if there are any foreign keys enabled, but that's about it.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME ='my_table';
```

Based on how you describe the tables, the given design sounds... odd. I hope whoever designed it left you documentation. Your last resort is going to be just dumping the data and looking for patterns.